# Module is not defined error angularjs after using webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack

My webpack.config

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

entry: "./main.js", //relative to root of the application
output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "app.bundle.js" //relative to root of the application
},
watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        hash: true,
        title: 'My Awesome application',
        myPageHeader: 'interviewee',
        template: './_index.html',
        filename: 'index.html' //relative to root of the application
    })
]
```

}

main.js

```
    let jquery = require("./Scripts/jquery-1.9.0.js");
    let angular = require("./Scripts/angular.js");
    let ngRoute = require("./Scripts/angular-route.js");
    let bootstrap = require("./Scripts/bootstrap.js");
    let appController = require("./app.controller.js");
    let addController = require("./add.controller.js");
    let service = require("./service.js");
    let messages = require("./Scripts/angular-messages.js")
```

app.controller

```
    var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", [
        'ngRoute',
        'ngMessages',
        'IntervieweeService'
        ]
    );
    MyApp.config(['$routeProvider',
        function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/Add', {
                    templateUrl: 'Views/add.html',
                    controller: 'AddController'
                }).

                otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/Home'
                });
        }]
    );
```

add.controller

```
    MyApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope, EmpApi) { ....... }
```

When I run the app, I get 'MyApp' is not defined. What am I doing wrong? I am new at both webpack and angularjs. Could you please show me how do I fix this too? Thanks

Comment: Is this minifies the angular code?

Answer (score 1):

Change Your controller dependencies in a way that minified version will understand. i.e.

`MyApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope, EmpApi) { ....... }`

to

```
MyApp.controller("AddController", addController);

addController.$inject = ['$scope', 'EmpApi'];

function addController($scope, EmpApi){...};
```

Comment: While this is still good advice, if it was the main issue, wouldnt the error be something related to missing `$scope` or `EmpApi`, and not an error about `MyApp`?

Comment: It still shows the same error. 'ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined'

Comment: @chiliNUT, it shows sometimes same error if it is not formatted correctly.

Comment: @Thunfische, can you Share HTML, Also what happens if you don't use webpack? Another suggestion, create separate files for each thing and then try.

Comment: @Thunfische, I think the error should be in addController file as you have to `import` / make `require` - `app.controller`  (file name should corrected as per functionality)

Answer (score 0):

'MyApp' is not defined in the controller file so you will have to add the controller to the 'MyApp' module

Change

```
MyApp.controller("AddController", function ($scope, EmpApi) { ....... }
```

To

```
angular.module('MyApp').controller("AddController", function ($scope, EmpApi) { ....... }
```